# LinqToSQL - Effecient handling of objects - Retrieving first/single iobject

Tags: c#, database, linq, linq-to-sql

The last few weeks I have been working with `LinqToSql`, I love it and the community here is fantastic.

I created a query to find an Object in the Database and update the values, It seems to work fine, but the code doesn't look natural to me, I would imagine there is a better solution.

Please review the code below;

```
        //Return a list of MyObject items
        // irrelevant line, just to show what the objects are
        List<MyObject> items  = Factory.GetObjects(); 

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var myObjects= from myobj in db.MyOjects
                             where myobj.id == item.Key
                             select myobj;

            //Should ONLY find 1 object 
            //Below is the code I think we could optimize
            if (myObjects.Count() == 1)
            {
                myObjects.First().propertyToChange1 = item.p1;
                myObjects.First().propertyToChange2 = item.p2;
                myObjects.First().dateAltered = DateTime.Now;

                //Update DB
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }





        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution is to use `SingleOrDefault`, like this:

```
var myObject = db.MyOjects.SingleOrDefault(myobj => myobj.id == item.Key);
if (myObject != null) {
    myObject.propertyToChange1 = item.p1;
    myObject.propertyToChange2 = item.p2;
    myObject.dateAltered = DateTime.Now;
    //Update DB
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: nice :), thats fantastic, what is the ( => )

Comment: @IEnumerable That's a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) - a function with no name.

Answer (score 1):

you can also approach it with first or default in a regular query way

```
var myObjects= (from myobj in db.MyOjects
                             where myobj.id == item.Key
                             select myobj).FirstOrDefault();
          if (myObjects != null)
            {
                myObjects.First().propertyToChange1 = item.p1;
                myObjects.First().propertyToChange2 = item.p2;
                myObjects.First().dateAltered = DateTime.Now;

                //Update DB
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }
```